# SONAR: Replace with lambda with a method reference with a string parameter

Tags: lambda, java-8, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

```
 List<String> list;
 //...add something in the list
String value = "anything";
boolean b = list.stream().anyMatch( element -> value.startsWith(element))
```

I get the sonar information about Replace with lambda with a method reference. But I have to call method reference on String ???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String value = "anything";
boolean b = list.stream().anyMatch( value::startsWith);
```

Or you don't even need to declare `String value`, you can use "anything" directly in the lambda expression:

```
list.stream().anyMatch( "anything"::startsWith)
```